# Send notification to status bar if app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When I am receiving a push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging and my app is in background I receive this notification to android's syste status bar.
However if my app is in background I do not receive it but instead `onMessageReceived` is raised.

Is it possible to show this notification if app is in foreground mode?
I know I can use NotifictionManager and build this notificatioin manually but there should be an easier way which Firebase SDK uses if app is in background. Like

```kotlin
class FcmService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        showNotificationInStatusbar(message)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firebase officially supports this. Please see these two docs  [Receive messages in an Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) , [About FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.